# Программа выдаёт ошибку Temp.exe trigerred a breackpoint

Tags: c++

Название проекта Temp.exe
Почему в этому коде выдаёт такую ошибку

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {

    int sizeArr2 = 0;
    int* arr2 = new int[sizeArr2];

    arr2[sizeArr2++] = rand()%10;
    arr2[sizeArr2++] = rand() % 10;
    arr2[sizeArr2++] = rand() % 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeArr2; i++) {
        cout<< arr2[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем вы создаете массив, размером 0 элементов?

Comment: ```c++
int sizeArr2 = 0; int* arr2 = new int[sizeArr2]; arr2[sizeArr2++] = rand()%10; arr2[sizeArr2++] = rand() % 10; arr2[sizeArr2++] = rand() % 10;
``` Как, по-Вашему, это будет работать, если массив изначально объявлен с 0 элементами (т.е. пустым?) UPD: вижу, что кто-то поставил минус без указания причин =/ Тем не менее, я перепроверил код на некоторых онлайн-компиляторах, я увидел, что он работает. Тем не менее, исходя из логики, такое *не должно* работать, и Ваш компилятор, судя по всему, посчитал точно так же, раз он выкинул такую ошибку. На будущее могу посоветовать либо заранее определ

Answer (score 1):

Вы создаете массив из нуля элементов.

```
int sizeArr2 = 0;
int* arr2 = new int[sizeArr2];  // <-- здесь sizeArr2 равно 0
```

Далее вы записываете в первый, чторой и так далее **несуществующие** элементы массива некоторые данные, т.е. выходите за границы массива. Такое поведение является неопределенным, и может приводить к чему угодно, в том числе и к аварийному завершению программы.

```
arr2[sizeArr2++] = rand()%10;
```

Comment: А как менять размер массива во время выполнения программы?

Comment: Или есть только способ когда я узнаю условия а только потом присваиваю размер массива исходя из условий?
Просто если там функция random и я не знаю какой размер массива может быть 1раз он 50 2раз он уже 150 и как потом присвоить например 99 элементу имеенно то значение которое срандомилось именно тогда?

Comment: Менято — создавать новый нужного размера, перекопировать туда элементы из старого.